# TYPO3 7.6 TCEFORM Custom Layouts doesn't work

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I upgraded TYPO3 6 to 7.6.x and now I can't choose custom layouts in the backend for any content elements in the backend. I only see the default options like "layout 1, layout 2". The reason is obviously that my TCEFORM addings doesn't work..

The following typoscript won't have any effect in a ext-template of a page or in the root setup.ts:

```
TCEFORM.tt_content.layout.altLabels.2 = Test
TCEFORM.tt_content.layout.removeItems = 2,3
TCEFORM.tt_content.layout.addItems.5 = New Item
```

I know the problem description is a bit inaccurate. But I don't see the relevant infos which u need. Can u give me an advice what I have to check? Are there known conflicts with extension like fluidcontent, css_styled_content or so?

Answer (score 0):

TypoScript configuring the back end is (though TypoScript by syntax) often called TSConfig and can be added either in page records or via user settings but never in extension templates or similar.

Configuring TCEFORM is usually done in page properties. To add, open page properties of your root page (or the topmost page of the subtree you want to configure) and [add your code there](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TSconfigReference/PageTsconfig/Field/Index.html).

As in front-end TypoScript you can swap your code to external files.

Comment: ty for the quick advice and explanation, that works for me too. I promise I will read more about the usage, differences of TSConfig, extension template, etc. I thought it doesn't matter where it is written down -_-

Comment: It‘s definitely worth reading up about TypoScript (Constants, Setup, PageTsConfig, UserTsConfig, assignments, value modifications etc.). It‘s important to distinguish between parse time and run time etc. Good starting point for read-up is [TypoScript Syntax Reference](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptSyntaxReference/Index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this typoscript on `Root Page` in `Page TSconfig`.

Edit root page properties and add your typoscript in `Resources` tab in `Page TSConfig` section  like below image, so it's work fine.

[image]

Comment: ty for the quick advice and explanation, that works for me too